# VS Team Services - Build Tasks - Knowing linked work item types

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

On a build task, I want to know the work items number and types that are present [Product Backlog Item, Bug]on a build.

The need come to accomplish an versioning with this types. Something like this:

```
2.1.3 –> 1 feature –> 2.2.0
2.1.3 –> 1 feature, 3 bugs –> 2.2.3
2.1.3 –> 2 features, 4 bugs –> 2.3.4
2.1.3 –> 3 bugs –> 2.1.6
```

Is in vsts build task any variable to get this information?

Comment: Do you want to check the work items when edit the task or during the build?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT is during the build. The possibility to know the work items are linked

Comment: Do you mean the associated wits of current build?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT yes, the associated works of the current build

Comment: When to display this information? Build running, build finished or edit the build task?

Comment: In the build running, I can programmatically se how much features and bugs are linked. And with this information, update the version number.

Answer (score 1):

No, there has no such existing build tasks or variables to get VSTS build linked work items.

But you can achieve it by the REST API [Get Work Items Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

Such as you can add a PowerShell task to execute the the REST API and get the linked work items between current build and pervious build, then get the work item type and count separately.